# VS Code keybind for quick formatting a selection on HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, keymapping

I recently switched from Brackets to VS Code and I can't find a specific keyboard shortcut that I used regularly on Brackets, and I can't custom create it because I don't know how to correctly describe the command to the program.

On Brackets I used to use the keyboard shortcut **Shift+Ctrl+A** and with a few lines selected it would let me format the complete selection. It opened a one-line command screen on the bottom and it would let me add up different tags for HTML for example. Let's say I had a few paragraphs that I needed to format into an ol, once selected I would simply type:  **ol>li*** in the command screen and it would automatically format the whole selection.

English is not my first language so sorry if the explanation is kind of weird! I've been searching for a solution to this for some days and I'm getting nowhere.

Things I already tried/worth noting:

- Installed the Brackets keymap extension (I went through all of the keybinds and couldn't replicate this)
- Checked VSCode keybinds list.
- I, unfortunately, uninstalled Brackets and can't take a screenshot of the thingy. I am regretting this so much already. I should have been more aware of the keyboard shortcuts and whatever extensions I had installed.
- Maybe it has to do with an extension that I'm forgetting to install?

Comment: Look at `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`, they changed the name a bit in 1.54. You can use Multi Cursor

Comment: Thank you!! That was it. :)